# run python scripts on apache (linux and windows)

Tags: python, linux, windows, apache

I need help with how to run scripts test.cgi for example in apache ?
I  created test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!
```

When I run`localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi`

It gives me error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Python is installed properly.
Test.cgi chmod is 755

I am new to linux. On wndows it gives me error too .
On windows it gives me:

```
End of script output before headers: python_test.cgi
```

I use this script on windows:

```
#!"C:\Python34\python.exe"
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: can you please show the configuration in your `httpd.conf` file ?

Comment: In linux is empty and windows is ok cause perl scripts works fine.
I added LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so   and   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these to your configuration file:

```
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/python">
      Options +ExecCGI
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

and replace your code with:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print ("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print ()

print ("Hello World!")
```

It worked for me. In Python 3.x `print` is a function, so you have to pass the string to be printed as an arguement.

Comment: On windows ?
I use xampp on windows and only apache on linux.

Comment: Yes, there would be a `httpd.conf` file in xampp

Comment: I know, I edited it before to enable cgi_mod. I andded it but it did not work.
I am using python3.4 can it make this error ?