# Viewing Cloud Compute Engine Application in Web Browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, plotly-dash

I have a Dash application that I can run locally and view in my browser. I have moved it to Google Cloud Compute Engine and the app runs, but I can't see it in my browser at the 127.0.0.1 address where it's running. 
I have tried to allow http and https traffic to the virtual machine using 
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create FIREWALL_RULE --allow tcp:80,tcp:443` in the console without any luck. How can I view it in my browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were able to reach `http://127.0.0.1` and/or `https://127.0.0.1` when you run it locally because you run your web browser on the same computer. More information you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> The local loopback mechanism may be used to run a network service on a
>   host without requiring a physical network interface, or without making
>   the service accessible from the networks the computer may be connected
>   to. **For example, a locally installed website may be accessed from a
>   Web browser by the URL http://localhost to display its home page.**
>
> The name localhost normally resolves to the IPv4 loopback address
>   127.0.0.1, and to the IPv6 loopback address ::1.

As result, you can access IP `127.0.0.1` located on your VM instance **only from your VM instance**.

**To check your application on IP `127.0.0.1`** you can use command `curl` from command line of your VM instance:

```
instance:~$ curl -I http://127.0.0.1
instance:~$ curl -I https://127.0.0.1
```

**To allow access to your application via ports 80/443** you should go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE`-> click on **`EDIT`** -> go to **`Firewalls`** and select `Allow HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTP traffic` -> click `Save`. Have a look at the documentation [Firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) and [Configuring network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to find more details.

**To access your application from web browser** you should use external IP address that you can find at `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> look for `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` and **`External IP`**:

```
http://EXTENAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
https://EXTENAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After doing this I'm only seeing a default index page instead of the application when it's running. Do you know why this might be? Elsewhere I see that application files often tend to be stored in the `/var/www' directory and an index.html file is present but I have a single app.py file, do I need to to something different for this to show up? Or move it to a certain directory? (I tried moving it to the above mentioned location with no success). Thanks.

Comment: You should configure web server. Have a look at these examples https://stackoverflow.com/q/40498208/12428794,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565361/12428794 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831634/12428794 (just replace localhost with external IP). If it's not solve your problem just post another question because it's a different field.